# MVC .net web API and MVC app in same project

Tags: .net, web-services, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a solution where I android app will consume web services. And there should be a website as well.
So I am thinking to create MVC web API for all business logic including user authentication in web service then consume those from MVC Web App.
(1). Is it a good design?
(2). I am new to web services. I think there are only limited functions like GET, PUT, POST, how can I create many other functions for my business logic.
(3). I s there any example available for this design?
I basically want Web api and MVC front end.
Please help.
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "MVC Web Service" in the ASP.NET world.

Comment: Be aware that in MS .Net framework, a "webservice" is a legacy technology. You probably need a web api, not a webservice.

Comment: I meant Web API 2. I have updated my question. Please help

Comment: The answer is opinion-based, hence I don't think your question is suitable for Stackoveflow. 1) yes, it is okay to have a web api and an MVC web site in your solution if you're going to need both. 2) Rest web api use http verbs like GET, PUT, POST, etc, but this is not a limitation as you can have multiple resources supporting some or all those verbs. 3) it is plenty of samples, just Google.

Comment: There are plenty of on-topic portions of this question. Can i host a Web API and an MVC site in the same project? 2) Does MVC support all HTTP verbs? 3) Can anyone provide an example on how to do put them in the same project? The only off-topic part of this question is 1) Is it good design? Ok, sure, but even that is implying "does this sound like an approach that will impose unnecessary difficulties?

I think you're being too harsh either because he used the word "good", or because you' have'nt spent much time trying to do this yourself. It's not easy, and it's not primarily opinion-based.

Comment: That being said, I do think the question is too broad, but not off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC supports all HTTP verbs. Some of them have their own attributes, but for the others you will need to use `[AcceptVerbs("SomeVerb")]`. You could even use this for

Yes, you can put multiple web applications in the same project. One way to do that is to use Map on your `IApplicationBuilder` instance within your `Startup` class's `Configure` method.:

```
app.Map("api", apiApp =>
    {
        // any middleware registered here will only run for "/api/*" URIs.
    }
);
```

But that only effects which middle-wares run. You may still need to register your controllers routes appropriately.

```
[Route("api/contacts")]
public class ContactApiController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

As for whether or not this is a "good design", all I can tell you is that there's nothing glaringly wrong with this approach. It's just a matter of what works best for you and your project. Personally, I have a separate project for my API server, and one project for each of my APIs which the server project reference and registers with MVC. The other server just serves up static content and a single page application. There are any number of ways to do this.